# Hacker Experience Safenet firewall version?

Tags: hacker-experience

As the title says, does anyone know what version is the firewall for Safenet? Or what cracker version do I need for hacking Safenet. I'm in no need to hack Safenet, but I would just like to. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a cracker that's 5.0 or above. If you're going to hack into safenet via exploitation, you need an exploit that's 3.5 or above.